# Is there an "and" symbol?

Tags: notation

I was wondering if there was a symbol for "and"? For example, I want to say something like

$\therefore a = b \,  \text{and} \, c = d $

Then can I replace "and" with a symbol?

Thanks!

Comment: Though your mathematical argument may be much more legible if you write "Therefore, $a=b$ and $c=d$." (Unless you specfically want to prove a statement formally expressed using first order logic - but then you'd already know the $\land$ symbol ...)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks, I didn't know that. Is it general practice to use symbols only when you're proving something? or do you use them at convenience?

Comment: Just use a cost/benefit analysis.  Costs: 1. People unfamiliar with this notation (like yourself a matter of minutes ago) will have to deduce (or guess) what it means.  2. `\wedge` takes more effort to type in LaTeX than `and`.  Benefits: 1. Could potentially result in a better line break. 2. Looks more mathsy (useful for grant writing).  Anything I've missed?

Comment: I agree that its better not to use too many logic symbols. Then people end up having to try and decipher all the symbols if there are too many. But sometimes they are helpful if a statement has ambiguities in interpretation (then the logic symbols will help to write exactly what you mean).

Comment: the wedge is standard and it is standard not to use brackets around the a=b \land c=d but i do prefer it with brackets so that it becomes  (a = b) \land (c = d)

Comment: Line breaking in the middle of an equation is close to the worst line breaking there is!

Comment: Also $\&$, I think. (Even if it's not standard, everyone'll know what you mean.) And writing "and" is fine provided the intended readers know English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"And": The [logical symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) for *and* is given by $ \land$ (known as the "wedge" symbol). And for future reference, the logical symbol for *or* is given by $\lor$, sometimes called "vee".

In your case, you can express $a = b\;\; \text{and}\;\; c = d$ as:
$$a = b\, \land\, c = d$$

Comment: For formatting in latex/mathjax: $P \land Q$ is given by `P \land Q` or by `P \wedge Q`.

Comment: +1 How does this symbol wedge spell in speaking, Amy? Can I spell it as "$P$ and $Q$"?

Comment: @amWhy: Can use another TU! +1

Comment: @BabakS. Yes, it's simply read "P and Q". The name wedge is just a "name" of the symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. The symbol $\land$ is the most common. You can look at all types of logic symbols here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols